# RegEx for capturing an element textContent

Tags: python, regex

Just trying to grab the titles of events from a website and I have most of them, but It won't pick up one title. The missing result is:

> AFL U16’s Championships

Can someone tell me what I need to change in my Regex to find this?

```
from re import *
from urllib.request import urlopen

Website = 'https://thegabba.com.au/what-s-on.aspx'
print('Now Gathering Results from URL: ' + Website)

html_source = urlopen(Website).read().decode("UTF-8")
EventMatches = findall('<h6 class="event-title">([A-Za-z0-9\'\\s]+)</h6>',html_source)

print('There are ' + str(len(EventMatches)) + ' Events.')

for EventNames in EventMatches:
    print(EventNames)
```

Comment: @Emma The output looks like this https://imgur.com/a/t8u6L1r and the desired output is the same, except with an additional result, which is the     AFL U16’s Championships

Comment: Anyone trying to parse HTML with a regexp should be aware: [the pony, he comes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/238884).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression we might want here would be:

```
<h6 class="event-title">(.+?)<\/h6>
```

which captures everything in the `h6` tags.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/VY64M7/1)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"<h6 class=\"event-title\">(.+?)<\/h6>"

test_str = "<h6 class=\"event-title\">Brisbane Lions v Hawthorn Football Club and Anthing else we wish here including @#$%^&*(</h6>"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The apostrophe `’` is *not* the same as the single quote `'`. You need to allow for the former as well as the latter if you want that result included.

Comment: So how do I include a single quote?

Comment: @ZooKeeper, you *have* the single quote, what you need is the apostrophe. Just add it to the `[A-Za-z0-9\'\\s]` character class using whatever encoding you have (it's not ASCII, I'm assuming it's Unicode since you mention `UTF-8`).).

Answer (score 0):

content was actually returning binary not utf-8/ascii so decoded to iso-8895-1

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re
import requests

Website = 'https://thegabba.com.au/what-s-on.aspx'
print('Now Gathering Results from URL: {}'.format(Website))

html_source = requests.get(Website).content.decode('ISO-8859-1') 
EventMatches = re.findall(r'<h6 class="event-title">([A-Za-z0-9\'\s]+)<\/h6>', html_source)

print('There are {} Events.'.format(len(EventMatches)))

for EventNames in EventMatches:
    print(EventNames)
```

```
Now Gathering Results from URL: https://thegabba.com.au/what-s-on.aspx
There are 14 Events.
Brisbane Lions v Hawthorn Football Club
Brisbane Lions v Melbourne Football Club
Brisbane Lions v North Melbourne Football Club
Stadium Stomp
Brisbane Lions v Western Bulldogs
Brisbane Lions v Gold Coast Suns
Muscle Up For MND
Brisbane Lions v Geelong Football Club
Australia v Sri Lanka
Australia v Pakistan
Pakistan v New Zealand
Australia v A1
New Zealand v A1
England v Afghanistan
```